# SQL Replace command with wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, wildcard

Basically I'm trying to replace everything in a string that is within brackets.

So for example the string of '123[1abc]abc' would become '123[xx]abc'

```
select replace(string,'[%]','[xx]') as string2 from table1
```

Except of course that won't work.

The value within the brackets is always different, and it is simply not feasible to find all the individual possibilities. In addition, some of the values within the brackets also appear outside of the brackets, but I only want them changed for the part within.

I'm working in Microsoft SQL Server if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there is only one such expression and the square braces only appear once, you can use `stuff()` to construct the string:

```
select stuff(str,
             charindex('[', str) + 1,
             charindex(']', str) - charindex('[', str) - 1,
             'xx')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with string manipulation. Take the left of the string up to the left bracket, add 'xx' and then add the right side starting with the right bracket.

```
SELECT LEFT(string, CHARINDEX('[', string)) 
       + 'xx' 
       + RIGHT(string, LEN(string) - CHARINDEX(']', string) + 1) AS string2
    FROM table1;
```